# Draw the graph of $y = \frac{\sqrt{x + 1}}{x - b}$ with $ 1 < b < 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Draw the graph of the function $y = \frac{\sqrt{x + 1}}{x - b}$ with $ 1 < b < 2$ (qualitatively accurate)**

I'm not looking for help on how to find asymptotes and extrema in general and I'm also familiar with the second derivative tests to determine concativity of regions of the curve.

But what I'm not familiar with is the introduction of a 'variable constant' (or whatever the correct term is). Since the value of $b$ determines the location of the vertical asymptotes, but no further information is given.

Please do not give full answers, I really want to solve this myself, but a small hint regarding the use of $b$ would be helpful.

Comment: $$x=b$$ is one asymptote and the $x$ axses

Comment: Start by playing with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cunqbve98e

Comment: Am I just overthinking this and should I just take some allowed value of $b$ and go with that?

Comment: Yes. Just pick one, draw the picture, be done.

Comment: You could also see, show and prove that, when $x\to\infty$, $y\sim \frac 1{\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 0):

Draw the graph,  write your x axis in terms of b